# Why Wendy gets angry and leaves?

Tags: character, mindhunter-2017

In *Mindhunter*, 6th episode, there is a scene that *Wendy Carr* having a dinner with her girlfriend and other two males in a restaurant, Wendy informs her girlfriend that she has been offered a full time job by the FBI.

It shows Wendy clearly getting upset when her girlfriend holds her hand in front of that other two males. She stand up and leaving without even saying goodbye.

why she leave with so much anger?

Comment: It seems she needed to avoid public display of affection or something like that

Comment: @Vishwa, yes, I agree but there is more to it.

Comment: It could be. couldn't find any sources nor the time to do any research. Although Paulie_D provides a very good answer below..

Comment: I think it might have to do with a cobination of "show" vs dominence, because Lena Olin's character comes off as controlling and perhpas a bit manipulative. So I'm not sure if it's public display alone, even though sure, that's a concern, but I think since they were with friends, it was more about about pushing Wendy, instead of respecting her or waiting for her cues.

Comment: @DarthLocke, yeah, fully agreed. When I watched that scene, I felt a bit surprised as between two highly intelligent women, this kind of trick is below them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's no evidence of **anger** as such although I suppose one could interpret it that way. Wendy is quite calm throughout the whole scene.

What it *appeared to me* was that Wendy wasn't comfortable with the public display of affection that her girlfriend was making by holding her hand.

It's not clear whether the relationship between the women is public (or even if the two men at the table were aware of it) but what *is* certain is that the FBI would have disapproved of any such relationship given the times they were living in.

In fact the whole conversation is about public embarrassment and keeping part of oneself private which adds an extra layer to it since Wendy can't say that she's working with the FBI because it would "reflect badly" on Wendy's girlfriend.

Added to that is the conversation prior to that scene where Wendy's girlfriend was basically suggesting that Wendy's work with the FBI wasn't important and that what *was important* was getting tenure and improving ones standing at the university.